# Why is Apache Sedona not reading this Shapefile properly?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, geospark

I'm using Apache Spark v3.0.1 and Apache Sedona v1.1.1 and I'm trying to read a Shapefile into a `SpatialRDD`. I first tried the [example](https://github.com/apache/incubator-sedona/blob/master/examples/sql/src/main/scala/ScalaExample.scala) provided by the Sedona library (more specifically, the code inside `testShapefileConstructor` method), and it just worked. However, when I try to read another Shapefile, despite the fact that metadata was loaded correctly, the actual data was missing. Using `count` on the `SpatialRDD` gives me 0.

The shapefile I'm using is available [here](https://dados.gov.br/dataset/malha-geometrica-dos-municipios-brasileiros/resource/faf127dc-3be3-42c9-9c52-56baf76718ac). It's the map of a Brazilian state. Since I tried with data from other states, I guess there's something wrong with those files.

And this is the code I used. I'm aware that the contents of the shapefile reside in a folder with `.shp`, `.shx`, `.dbf` and `.prj` files, so the variable `path` to that folder.

```scala
import org.apache.sedona.viz.core.Serde.SedonaVizKryoRegistrator
import org.apache.sedona.core.formatMapper.shapefileParser.ShapefileReader
import org.apache.sedona.sql.utils.{Adapter, SedonaSQLRegistrator}
import org.apache.sedona.viz.sql.utils.SedonaVizRegistrator
import org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, DataFrame, Encoder}

object Main {

def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
      .config("spark.serializer", classOf[KryoSerializer].getName)
      .config("spark.kryo.registrator", classOf[SedonaVizKryoRegistrator].getName)
      .appName("test")
      .getOrCreate()

    SedonaSQLRegistrator.registerAll(spark)
    SedonaVizRegistrator.registerAll(spark)

    val path = "/path/to/shapefile/folder"
    val spatialRDD = ShapefileReader.readToGeometryRDD(spark.sparkContext, path)
    println(spatialRDD.fieldNames)
    println(spatialRDD.rawSpatialRDD.count())
    var rawSpatialDf = Adapter.toDf(spatialRDD, spark)
    rawSpatialDf.show()
    rawSpatialDf.printSchema()
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[ID, CD_GEOCODM, NM_MUNICIP]
0
+--------+---+----------+----------+
|geometry| ID|CD_GEOCODM|NM_MUNICIP|
+--------+---+----------+----------+
+--------+---+----------+----------+
root
 |-- geometry: geometry (nullable = true)
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CD_GEOCODM: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NM_MUNICIP: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried changing the character encoding, as pointed out [here](https://sedona.apache.org/api/sql/Constructor/#read-esri-shapefile), but the results were the same after these attempts:

```scala
System.setProperty("sedona.global.charset", "utf8")
```

and

```scala
System.setProperty("sedona.global.charset", "iso-8859-1")
```

So I still have no idea why this fails to be read. What could be problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Sedona only supports Shapefile type Point, Polyline, Polygon, and MultiPoint (i.e., type 1, 3, 5, 8) according to https://github.com/apache/incubator-sedona/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/sedona/core/formatMapper/shapefileParser/parseUtils/shp/ShapeType.java

But your data might be something else because Shapefile specification supports more types: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile

Comment: I'm not sure this warning had always been there, but today I've seen it: `[SEDONA] Shapefile type POLYGONM is not supported. Skipped this record.`

Comment: Yes, we added this warning last year to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using the `Wegsegment` shapefile from https://www.geopunt.be/download?container=wegenregister&title=Wegenregister (which is the Flemish road register).
I could open the file just fine with [QGIS](https://qgis.org/), I exported it from there with GeometryType `LineString` instead of `Automatic` and the export worked fine in Sedona. I noticed the original had LineStringM features (if you just add the layer and then hover over it). When I examined the m ordinate (cf. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/274117/211228) it turned out to be empty, so don't think I lost anything there. Seems yours is a Polygon, but exporting with type Polygon instead of Automatic also makes it possible to read with Sedona.